# Why is AWS Greengrass region specific?

Tags: aws-iot, aws-greengrass

When I try to go through the AWS Greengrass functionalities it gives me a message saying;

> "Region Unsupported. AWS Greengrass is not available in US... Please
>   select another region. "

Of course they allowed me to change the region and try out the functionalities. But what is the reason that this is region specific?

Comment: That's odd... The [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/faqs/) specifically says "You can use AWS Greengrass regardless of your geographic location, as long as you have access to one of the above AWS regions." and lists two US AWS regions. The error message seems to contradict that.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. Even they allow me to pick any region. May be their servers deployed on those regions. In order to get faster communication they must asking users to pick the closet region to them.

Comment: Which region were you on ? There's 4 US regions and only 2 supported. If I try on us-west-1 I get the message: "AWS Greengrass is not available in US West (N. California). Please select another region."  which makes sense  as it is not in the supported list. (as for the reason, AWS usually deploy new services on some regions and extend on an opportunist way with maintenances on other regions)

Comment: Did you ask Amazon? They might know

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Amazon's deployment strategy is known only to its business strategists - we can deal in facts here, but unless Amazon posts a "why" all that a 3rd party can do is speculate, and speculation is not a role of the Stack Exchange system.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Web Services that have been created under the free usage tier seem to be region-specific.  In the past I have had to go region=specific to connect to beta services when implementing them. I would expect that after 12 months of "free" service, the author of these kinds of projects will be required to subscribe to a paid level appropriate for the usage expected.  There is a serious revenue model associated with AWS.